# Commander vs ordonner

Tags: verbes, synonymes

Is there any difference in meaning between "commander" and "ordonner" when they mean "to give an order to somebody"? Are both usual?

Example:

- *Le professeur a commandé à l'élève de se taire.*
- *Le professeur a ordonné à l'élève de se taire.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference in meaning but a significant one in usage.

1. ***Ordonner*** is strong and what would be used for a demand<sup>1</sup>. An alternative would be:

   > Le professeur a donné l'ordre de se taire à l'élève.
2. ***Commander** à quelqu'un de faire quelque chose* is an outdated, literary way to express the same but unlikely to be used in modern French.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Beware that *demander* just means "to ask", not "to demand".</sub>

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference; "commander (à qqn) de + inf." and "Ordonner de + inf. (à qqn.)" are synonyms.